# Drupal Module help required

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

```
function nat_customForms_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()){
// set up an empty array which will contain the block contents
$block = array();

switch ($op) {
  case "list":
    drupal_set_message('<h1 style="color:orange;">>Medjool List </h1>');
    // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
    $block[0]["info"] = t('Medjool Dates are scrummy don\'t you know');
    //$block[0]["content"] = "list # list # list # list # list # list # list # list";
    $block[0]["content"] = _nct_customForms_CONTENT();
  break;

  case "view":
    drupal_set_message('<h1 style="color:purple;">>Medjool View </h1>');
    // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
    $block[0]["info"] = t('Medjool Dates are scrummy don\'t you know');
    $block[0]['status'] = 1;
    $block[0]["subject"] = 'SUBJECT Medjool SUBJECT';
    $block[0]["content"] = '####Medjool Dates are scrummy don\'t you know####';

case "save":
  break;

case "configure":
  break;
}
return $block;
//print render($block['content']);
}
```

Using Drupal 6 I am trying to get this block to output some content. I can see it when I assign it to a region in a panel but no content is being rendered. How do I make the content part of the block be rendered in the panel?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The above code started working for me after I removed the delta portion from the $block

eg.

```
$block[0]["info"] = t('Medjool Dates are scrummy don\'t you know');
```

turns into

```
$block["info"] = t('Medjool Dates are scrummy don\'t you know');
```

Weird since I specified $delta as being 0.